# How do I get a link to AppStore app image?

Tags: app-store

Is it possible to get a link to an app image in the app store (and how) ?

The Apple Link Maker (https://linkmaker.itunes.apple.com/), gives a badge that links to the full app App Store page, but I want to get the "big" app icon.

Of course, I gave that image to Apple, so I have it and could include it on the web page directly, but I want to simplify maintenance when the icon is modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple recently released a new tool that replaces itunes link maker. This tool can generates links to the app store image :

https://tools.applemediaservices.com/app-store